# withData and before are invoked at same time in webdriverio. How to invoke before first and then withData?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I have a data provider which gets the data from UI. For getting the data from UI, I am using before hook to open url and perform the required operations. But withData and before are invoked at same time ; Hence  dataprovider has 'undefined' value which leads to the failure.

```
describe('abcd', function(){
     before(function(){
         //get data
     });
     withData(data, function(value){
         it('abccd', function(){
           },)
     });
});
```

How can I achieve to get data first from UI and then pass it to dataprovider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things to check ...

**First,** make sure that you get the data either in a synchronous way or make `before` handle asynchronous code. Read about it here: [Mocha Asynchronous Code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code)

**Second,** I don't know how `withData` works, but you can nest your tests in a way that will make Mocha call `withData` after calling `before`.

**Third,** make sure that you use `data` in the right scope and not accidentally get a different one.

So with these suggestions your code might look something like:

```
describe('abcd', function() {
     var data = null; //declare data in a scope usable by `before` and `withData` functions

     before(function() {

         // get data synchronously
         data = 'some data';

         // or...

         //return a promise so the tests don't start before the promise resolves
         return getData().then(function (someData) {
           data = someData;
         })
     });

     // nested tests that will start only after `before` function finished executing
     describe('with data', function () {
         withData(data, function(value) {
             it('abccd', function() {
                //test
             });
         });
     });
});
```